# How to cache queries across page loads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app, I have a number of queries defined in application_controller.rb. The data returned by the query will change very infrequently.

Looking at the logs, these queries appear to be run on every page load.

How can I cache these arrays, so that they are refreshed less frequently, helping to increase page load time.

Thanks

Comment: Start here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Answer (score 1):

By using something like Memcached or Redis?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. Most simply, you can cache the queries in some instance variables across requests, with something like this:

```
@variable ||= Model.query
```

This will save them from being loaded on every request. However, if it's something that's very complex, you might consider throwing it in Redis (which is great for things like this).

Normally you wouldn't want to do something like this. You might want to reconsider the architecture of the app if you're doing something like this a lot.